# Inserting string from list to dataframe formula to loop calculation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Hope everyone is well, I am still very new at Python/Pandas and am wondering if the following is possible. I have a list of column/question names from my dataframe. I want to be able to pass them into my code

```
    Council     NPS EASE OSAT
0   CouncilA    5   99   2
1   CouncilB    0   4    2
2   CouncilC    4   1    5
3   CouncilA    1   4    5
4   CouncilB    3   1    3
5   CouncilC    1   4    3
6   CouncilA    4   1    99
7   CouncilB    4   4    1
8   CouncilC    3   3    3
9   CouncilA    2   2    1
10  CouncilB    4   99   4
11  CouncilC    2   2    5
```

Here is the code I am trying to update.

```
df = df[['Council', 'NPS', 'EASE', 'OSAT']]

percent4_5 = df[(df['NPS'] >= 4) & (df['NPS'] <=5 )].groupby(['Council'])['NPS'].count()
base = df[(df['NPS'] >= 0) & (df['NPS'] <=5 )].groupby(['Council'])['NPS'].count()
score = (percent4_5 / base)
```

At the moment, if I want to calculate the score for example 'EASE', I have to replace 'NPS' with 'EASE' as the base is different for each question. It would be great if the code could loop through the list and output a result for 'NPS', 'EASE', 'OSAT'.

I hope I am sticking to the etiquette in this forum. Please let me know if I am doing anything incorrectly.

Expected output from Excel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYXa0.png)

Comment: Almost there! Please edit to question and copy-paste the expected output as well instead of posting screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed almost there. Just set "Council" as the index, and repeat your operations, but on the DataFrame as a whole. `groupby` operations can be vectorised across the entire DataFrame.

```
df = df.set_index('Council')
percent4_5 = df[(df >= 4) & (df <= 5)].groupby(level=0).count()
base = df[(df >= 0) & (df <= 5)].groupby(level=0).count()

score = percent4_5 / base
print(score)
           NPS      EASE      OSAT
Council                           
CouncilA  0.50  0.333333  0.333333
CouncilB  0.50  0.666667  0.250000
CouncilC  0.25  0.250000  0.500000
```